# How do I keep the positions of my Buttons the same on a Canvas?

Tags: wpf, canvas

I have a WPF Window that has a Image in the background as a canvas. It is a picture of a pirate ship. I want to have buttons attached to certain points on the image which stay the same even if the size of the window is altered. With a fixed Window size this is fine. Can I select Hotspots at all where my Buttons will stay in touch with the same position on the image? Or do I use percentage positioning for the buttons?

This may be a lot to ask of WPF.

The buttons are on top of the canvas.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Background Image stretches according to Window Size, I'd use a `Converter` and set `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` based on a percentage.

You could either code your own `IValueConverter` that accepts the `Canvas.Height` and `Canvas.Width`, and a ConverterParameter identifying what percentage you want of the value, or I have a fairly generic [Math Converter on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/the-math-converter/) that you are free to use if you prefer.

```
<Button Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, ConverterParameter=@VALUE*.25}"
        Canvas.Left="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas, Path=ActualWith, Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, ConverterParameter=@VALUE*.25}" 
        ... />
```

(I forget if `Height`/`Width` or `ActualHeight`/`ActualWidth` is the more accurate value - you may need to test that one)

Comment: Rachel.. this is exactly what I needed. I have used your converter and your exact xaml code. When I resize the window, the buttons stay in the exact point I want them to. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a common ancestor of the canvas and buttons, give it a fixed size, and wrap it in a `Viewbox`.  Then you can let the `Viewbox` take care of scaling for you.  The entire scene--buttons, image, and anything else--will be scaled together, so you won't need to manually adjust any positioning.